# How can I change the default shortcuts in the "save" box

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a way to change the default shortcuts in the Windows Save box?  My machine shows

- My recent documents
- Desktop
- My documents
- My computer
- My network

I'd like to remove some and add others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non MSOffice applications (Office has its own dialogs):

**Method #1:**

Use Group Policy Editor to change things.

- Start | Run, type in gpedit.msc
- Navigate to User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer -> Common Open File Dialog

**Method #2:**

Use [**TweakUI**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe)

**Method #3:**

(standard warning for editing the registry applies.... :P)

The following key holds registry values that control items in the Windows Common Dialog (the Save, Open, Print etc dialog box):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32
```

You can add folders to this by adding values to this subkey (note that this key does not exist by default):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\PlacesBar
```

You add `STRING` values under the PlacesBar key named `Place#` where you replace # with a sequential integer.  Then set the value of that to be the folder path you want to have shown.

For example:

- `Place0` with a value of `C:\MyNewFolder`
- `Place1` with a value of `C:\Work`

As an aside, to totally hide the Places bar add a DWORD value under the `comdlg32` key called `NoPlacesBar` and set it to 1.

**For Office Apps, follow these links for instructions:**

- [**Office 2000**](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=205041)
- [**Office XP (2002), 2003, 2007**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826214)